# Generating C# classes for gml.xsd using MS Visual studio xsd tool

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd, gml

With Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 comes a tool called [xsd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) which can automatically generate C# source code to easily deal with XML files corresponding to a given schema. I have a very complex XSD schema based on the [GML](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gmlBase.xsd) schema. But after several days I had not even success to parse the GML schema standalone (without trying to parse my own 'custom schema').

Somehow the xsd tool seems to have problems following the included references for other referenced xsd schemas. Several forums advise to add these xsd files as command line parameter to the xsd call. But this doesn't work because suddenly some types are already defined. I suppose that the include happens in a circle. In the meantime I have already downloaded about 70 xsd schemas that are somehow used by GML schema (gco, gmd, gsr, gss, gts, ows, xlink). So I'm asking me if someone already successfully generated classes of the GML schema before?

Comment: This guy seems to have managed: https://oegeo.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/importing-the-gml-321-namespace-into-net/

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this one for years now:

http://www.xsd2code.com/